# Lookup in multi-matrix

Tags: excel

i have following structure in Excel:

[image]

where letters represent parameters and numbers represent values. From that structure, i need to do the new structure like this:

[image]

Every new  row must be combination of 4 letters from multi-matrix above and number, that represents value. How would you do that or how would you proceed with problem like this ?

Thanks

Comment: We would ask you to explain the output based on the input more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be too complicate to do so with formulas.
I suggest to do this with Macros:

```
Sub CustomTranspose()
Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Application.Range("C3:D6")
Dim cel As Range
For Each cel In rng
    Cells(cel, 6).Value = Cells(cel.Row, 1)
    Cells(cel, 7).Value = Cells(cel.Row, 2)
    Cells(cel, 8).Value = Cells(1, cel.Column)
    Cells(cel, 9).Value = Cells(2, cel.Column)
    Cells(cel, 10).Value = Cells(cel.Row, cel.Column)
Next cel
End Sub
```